# How to filter a SELECT result with IF condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that returns all employees. It gives me an error because it expects after the `WITH( )`, it expects a `SELECT` statement.

But if I would like to filter the result a second time, how do I work around using IF-ELSE IF?

Note: My SQL might sound a little confusing (i.e.: if @Gender = Male, look for all single employees) because those are placeholders I put in place of my real SQL. I apologize for not being too creative in naming.

```
DECLARE @Gender VARCHAR(10)
SET @Gender = 'Female'

/* Store all employees aged 50+ in a variable called queryResult */
WITH queryResult AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Age >= 50
)

/* If Gender = Male, I'm looking for all employees that are single */
IF @Gender = 'Male'
BEGIN
    SELECT * From queryResult WHERE Status = 'Single'
END

/* If Gender = Female, I'm looking for all employees that are married */
ELSE IF @Gender = 'Female'
BEGIN
    SELECT * From queryResult WHERE Status = 'Married'
END
```

**SOLVED:** In case you wanted to see my real query, here's my working query based on Rahul's answer.

```
WITH queryResult AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 t.userName, t.timeStamp
        FROM [Tracking].[dbo].[Tracking] t join (SELECT URL, PrimaryOwner FROM Governance WHERE Content = @Content) g
        ON t.referringURL like g.URL 
        WHERE 
            timeStamp >= 
                CASE WHEN @Frequency = 'Daily' THEN CAST(GETDATE() As Date)
                WHEN @Frequency = 'Monthly' THEN DATEADD(month, -1, CAST(GETDATE() As Date))
                WHEN @Frequency = 'Annually' THEN DATEADD(year, -1, CAST(GETDATE() As Date))
            END
            and PrimaryOwner = t.userName

        ORDER BY timestamp desc
    )

    SELECT * from queryResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the filtering in CTE itself like

```
DECLARE @Gender VARCHAR(10)
SET @Gender = 'Female'

WITH queryResult AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Age >= 50 AND Gender = @Gender
)    
select * from queryResult;
```

**EDIT:** In that case change your CTE with a `CASE` expression like below

```
DECLARE @Gender VARCHAR(10)
SET @Gender = 'Female'

WITH queryResult AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Age >= 50 
AND Status = CASE WHEN @Gender = 'Male' THEN 'Single' ELSE 'Married' END
)
SELECT * FROM queryResult;
```

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified my example. But here's my real dilemma: in my IF statements, it SELECTs the queryResult but with a different WHERE clause.

Comment: Per your edited post, queries are completely different when using with `IF .. ELSE` construct. In such case, no need of an CTE and just use the IF .. ELSE construct with your exact query.

Comment: I edited my query, basically I want to filter with something that's not a declared variable, but is a column in the table I just queried from. See edited query. @Rahul

Comment: how do I make multiple CASES? Like timestamp >= CASE WHEN Frequency = 'Daily', 'Monthly', 'Annually', etc.?

Comment: `timestamp >= CASE WHEN Frequency = 'Daily' THEN somecolumn/literal value WHEN Frequency = 'Monthly' THEN someother_column ELSE someothercolumn END`

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post to show my working query based on your answer.

Comment: FWIW, you don't even need the CTE at this point. If all you are doing is SELECT * FROM cte then you can just use the inner query directly.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
DECLARE @Gender VARCHAR(10)
SET @Gender = 'Female';

WITH queryResult AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Age >= 50
)
SELECT * From queryResult WHERE Gender = @Gender
```

EDIT:

If your WHERE clauses are very different you are likely better off putting the conditional on the outside. Putting the same cte or subquery in multiples places sort of offends the eye of a developer, but its could be the right answer here.

So to show that with your oversimplified example:

```
DECLARE @Gender VARCHAR(10)
SET @Gender = 'Female'

IF @Gender = 'Male'
BEGIN
    ;WITH queryResult AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Age >= 50
    )
    SELECT * From queryResult WHERE Gender = 'Male'
END

ELSE IF @Gender = 'Female'
BEGIN
    ;WITH queryResult AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Age >= 50
    )
    SELECT * From queryResult WHERE Gender = 'Female'
END
```

Comment: Per OP's edited post, a CTE doesn't have any meaning here since the queries are different without less commonality b/w them.

Comment: @KarlKieninger I edited my query, basically I want to filter with something that's not a declared variable, but is a column in the table I just queried from. See edited query.

Comment: I think we're losing to much in the simplification. As written you don't need the IF..ELSE construction or the CTE. It looks like you can do it with a compound WHERE clause using CASE.

Comment: @KarlKieninger Yes, I used CASE statements and it turned out to be a much simpler query. +1 to you, sir

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @Gender VARCHAR(10)
SET @Gender = 'Female'

WITH queryResult AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Age >= 50
)
select *
from queryResult
where
    (@Gender = 'Male' and Status = 'Single')
    or (@Gender = 'Female' and Status = 'Married')
```

Comment: No need for the OR statement at the end of the query. Simply Gender = @Gender will suffice.

Comment: @Hysteria86 it is surely  sufficient for the query in question, but I really think it is somehow simplified, and real condition will be somehow more complex then equality of variable and table column.

Comment: Maybe so, but that's not the scenario in the question. If we have SET @Gender = 'Female', as in the code, why would we need to check Female OR Male?

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified my example. But here's my real dilemma: in my IF statements, it SELECTs the queryResult but with a different WHERE clause.

Comment: @MarloC I have supposed some simplification here, that's why my answer was not with `WHERE Gender = @Gender` condition. More generally, if you have something like `if (condition_1) select ... where condition_2 else if (condition_3) select ... where condition_4` then it's equivalent to `select ... where (condition_1 and condition_2) or (condition_3 and condition_4)`

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I edited my query, basically I want to filter with something that's not a declared variable, but is a column in the table I just queried from. See edited query.

Comment: @MarloC but my answer (slightly updated) still fit that updated query. Just combination of conditions instead of `if`, and it works since `@Gender` can't be Male and Female in the same time.

Comment: Thanks @AndyKorneyev for your patience on this, but what if Gender is not what I'm filtering with in the WHERE clauses? See updated query again.

Comment: @MarloC is is no matter - if you filtering with gender or not. Read my comment about condition combination - it is 4 comments above of this one. And by the way - I've updated answer according to your latest edition of question.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Thanks, yes that works! However, I used the CASE statement given by Rahul since it's much cleaner. +1 for you, good sir!